# Need a tool to detect the type of variables in C code

Tags: python, c, compiler-construction

I am in a project developing specific source-to-source compiler. At this stage, I need to find the type of variables in a C source code. For example, if the code is `c[i]=j*f[k]+p;` I should find the type of `c`, `i`, `j`, `f`, `k`, and `p` variables (`int*`, `float`, and any other type defined in the source). Is there any tool to do so? If there are multiple tools, I prefer a python-based tool.

Thank you in ahead.

Comment: You're not going to get the types from pieces of code like that. You will get them from the respective *declarations.* Your question remains unclear.

Comment: Sure. Respective declarations are available in the full source. Please suppose the code is well-written and can be compiled. So we have all the corresponding declarations during parse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use [pycparser](https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pycparser) to write your own parser, you can find more examples [here](https://bitbucket.org/eliben/pycparser/src/c49f06f258b47311a653be40c4701ecb256fd6b3/examples?at=default)

```
from pycparser import c_parser
parser = c_parser.CParser()
text = 'int x; int y; float z;'
ast = parser.parse(text, filename='<none>')
ast.show()
FileAST: 
  Decl: x, [], [], []
    TypeDecl: x, []
      IdentifierType: ['int']
  Decl: y, [], [], []
    TypeDecl: y, []
      IdentifierType: ['int']
  Decl: z, [], [], []
    TypeDecl: z, []
      IdentifierType: ['float']
```

Comment: Small and handy tool! However, it looks it doesn't accepts all `C` statements. It works fine when the `text` is all variable declarations. Unfortunately, if the code contains assignment statements, the parser stucks! I should dig in to it to find out how it works. Thanks.

Comment: @ahmad I think it handles all valid C code, check out the example, you only need the declarations to find out the types of variables.

Comment: The example directory is much more informative than it looks. I think the `pycparser` can do what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you should be able to use the llvm-tools to create the [AST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) from the source code and then analyse the AST. except your task is to write something like the llvm-tools :)

here is an example of how to use the llvm-bindings for python to analyze a c-file:

http://www.mdevan.org/llvm-py/examples.html